# How to configure JSHint from within Coffeescript files?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jshint

When programming in Javascript it is possible to configure JSHint from within Javascript files using the following syntax

> /* jshint eqnull: true, eqeqeq: false */

Is there any way of setting those specific configurations from within a Coffeescript file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This coffeescript...

```
### jshint eqnull: true, eqeqeq: false ###

alert "regular coffee script here..."
```

### Compiles to...

```
/* jshint eqnull: true, eqeqeq: false */alert("regular coffee script here...");
```

### Need it on it's own line?

```
### jshint eqnull: true, eqeqeq: false ###
### break after hint ###
alert "regular coffee script here..."
```

### Compiles to...

```
/* jshint eqnull: true, eqeqeq: false */
/* break after hint */alert("regular coffee script here...");
```

Comment: It works! But raises a jhint error message of: 'unnecessary semicolon'

Comment: Maybe try without the extra `get a newline` comment. Is it necessary to have the desired jshint comment on it's own line?

Comment: Same thing. It appends a semicolon after jshint tags.